# Rails Object doesn't support #inspect error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, enums, associations

I'm creating an expense tracker application using Ruby on Rails 7.0. I have 3 models Account, Category, and Transaction.

This is how transactions migration looks:

```
class CreateTransactions < ActiveRecord::Migration[7.0]
  def change
    create_enum :transaction_type, %w[debit credit]
    create_table :transactions do |t|
      t.datetime :date
      t.string :description
      t.enum(:transaction_type, enum_type: 'transaction_type', null: false)
      t.decimal :amount
      t.string :notes
      t.references :account, null: false, foreign_key: true
      t.references :category, null: false, foreign_key: true

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

Below is the Transaction model.

```
class Transaction < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :account
  belongs_to :category

  enum :transaction_type, { debit: 'DEBIT', credit: 'CREDIT' }, prefix: true
end
```

I followed this [video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=H9W5dwHbY3Y&list=PLS6F722u-R6IJfBrIRx3a2SBkAL4vUp2p&index=5) and defined enums that way.  But when I hang around with the Transaction model on the rails console, it gives me this error `Object doesn't support #inspect error`

For example, `Transaction.transaction_type_debit` should return all the transactions with transaction_type of debit since `prefix: true` enables those methods. But it gives me the above error instead.

I suspect there's something with the associations with the other two models but still not sure exactly why and how to fix it.

Comment: I don't see any error in the code you posted. Can you please be more specific and tell us when you get the error? 

Other questions:
1. is the migration successful?
2. can you save and read a record in this model?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I figured out that the issue is with irb. What I did was just added `gem 'pry-rails'` and it replaced irb with pry. So, I'm not getting the error anymore with pry.